# Jest Test suite failed to run with await

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

I got a Javascript class with an `async` method (of course with `await` inside).

I'm trying to test this method, so I tried adding a test with this line:

```
const res = await myObj.theAsyncMethod("param");
```

this line causes an error:

> Test suite failed to run

and it points to the `await` as the error. If I remove the `await`, the test does not fail to run.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: 1st check, is the above code inside an async function? await calls cannot be resolved stand alone. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: The test of the it indeed wasn't async and that was the problem. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Provide more error detail. May be you missing `presets` for jest configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st check, is the above code inside an async function? await calls cannot be resolved stand alone.

Example for jest:

```
it("test async", async ()=> { ... });
```

Please refer to JS docs on async/await for examples.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function